# Android - Add numbers based on chosen radio buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app where the user can choose parts for a computer and the app updates the price in real time. The way I have it now, when something is selected, it overrides the price of anything else selected and replaces it with its own. This is what I have:

```
package com.bigtooth.uacs.pcbuild;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.bigtooth.uacs.pcbuild.R.id.pc;
import static com.bigtooth.uacs.pcbuild.R.id.price;
import static com.bigtooth.uacs.pcbuild.R.id.ram;

public class BuyExperionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RadioGroup radioGroupPc;
private RadioGroup radioGroupRam;
private RadioButton e5, e7, e9, ram8, ram16, ram32;
private TextView price;
private int ex5 = 550;
private int ex7 = 700;
private int ex9 = 1250;
private int ram8g = 0;
private int ram16g = 35;
private int ram32g = 70;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_experion);

    e5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.e5);
    e7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.e7);
    e9 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.e9);
    ram8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ram8);
    ram16 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ram16);
    ram32 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ram32);
    radioGroupPc = (RadioGroup)findViewById(pc);
    price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price);

    price.setText("$0");

    final RadioGroup categoryGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(pc);
    categoryGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.e5:
                    price.setText("$" + ex5);
                    ram8.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.e7:
                    price.setText("$" + ex7);
                    ram8.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.e9:
                    price.setText("$" + ex9);
                    ram16.setChecked(true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    RadioGroup categoryRam = (RadioGroup) findViewById(ram);
    categoryRam.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId) {
                case R.id.ram8:
                    price.setText("$" + ram8g);
                    break;
                case R.id.ram16:
                    price.setText("$" + ram16g);
                    break;
                case R.id.ram32:
                    price.setText("$" + ram32g);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

How can I make it so the prices of the items selected are added together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) to append the new value instead of replacing the previous one. Ex: `price.append("$" + ram32g);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you are trying, you will first need to create 2 `TextViews`. The first `TextView`, will have the text set as "$". The second will contain the value (by default it will be 0).

Next you can do the following:

```
categoryRam.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        int amount;
        switch(checkedId) {
            case R.id.ram8:
                amount = ram8g;
                break;
            case R.id.ram16:
                amount = ram16g;
                break;
            case R.id.ram32:
                amount = ram32g;
                break;
        }
            secondTextView.setText(amount + Integer.parseInt(secondTextView.getText()));
    }
});
```

Comment: It says there's and issue around secondTextView.getText()));

Comment: What does the error say? Change it to getText().toString()